# How to get data from smart contract faster

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, nethereum

I am currently using Nethereum, which is a C# wrapper to web3 where it makes about 1.2k requests within an hour on one thread.
I need to make about 30k requests within 1 hour.

How can I quickly retrieve data from smart contracts?
Is it possible to use a proxy?
When writing a proxy, I mean sending a request to an intermediary server that will send a request to the target smart contract on my behalf.
Or is there any other path that can help to solve this problem?

I am considering setting up my own node, but if there is any other way, I would rather avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

[Setting up your own node is the easiest to get data out from smart contract fastest](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513). Because any IO to your node is local, it is tens or hundreds of times faster than with a remote node. Any other trick does not come even close to this.

You can also parallelize queries. [Here is an example Python script that uses a thread pool to extract eth_getLogs over JSON-RPC](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/master/scripts/read-uniswap-v2-pairs-and-swaps-concurrent.py).